# JQuery Select2 - Re initialization with data not working

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, jquery-select2, jquery-select2-4

I am trying to replace data populated on page load via razor. I have three select2 comboboxes, Region, Clients and Issues. Region filters clients. I use the jquery select2 pluging on these comboboxes. I instantiate them on documet.ready. By default Clients just shows all the clients.  DropDowns.Clients is a universal list that contains the dropdown data.

```
$("#selectRegion").select2({
    placeholder: "Filter By Region",
    allowClear: true,
    width: '100%'

}).on("change", function (e) {

    debugger;
    var data = [];

    var regionID = $(this).val();

    $.each(DropDowns.Clients, function (idx, item) {
        if (item.regionID == regionID)
            data.push({ "id": item.clientID, "text": item.Name });
    })


    $("#selectClient").select2({
        data: data
    });

    debugger;
});


$("#selectClient").select2({
    placeholder: "Filter By Client",
    allowClear: true,
    width: '100%'

}).on("change", function (e) {

});
```

The function fires when I change the checkbox and the data array gets populated with the correct data but if I then set the data attr nothing changes. I have read through the currrent solutions on Stack Overflow but so far none oof them has worked so I think a second pair of eyes might do the trick. I am using v4 select2 should I consider going back to 2? Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Setting the data option will just reinitialize Select2 and add those options. You need to clear out the old options if your goal is to give it a new set of options to use.

Comment: @KevinBrown Yeah thank you that was the problem at the end.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I manage to solve the Issue with the following.

```
//Clear List
$("#selectIssue").select2().empty()

$("#selectIssue").select2({
    data: data,
    placeholder: "Filter By Issue",
    allowClear: true,
    width: '100%'
})
```